# Tags do not work on the Official Android app

Tags: bug, tags, android-app

I have installed [the official Android app](https://stackapps.com/q/4240/7653), and can input title and question.
But, when I tap on the *tags* field, I am taken to the tags screen which consists of a field with a magnifying glass to the left. If I type in tags, there is no sign of haptic feedback and the magnifier does not react.

If I tap on the 'DONE'  button nothing appears in the tag list at the bottom of the screen. Subsequently, if I press 'SUBMIT' the app manks because no tags are present and I cannot post.

Comment: This is about [the official android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin), right?

Comment: This bug report might be more at home on [meta.se].

Answer (score 2):

The behavior I've experienced is that with tags

- If a tag already exists, I can search for it and click it.
- If it doesn't exist (I have the rep to create one on this site), I can't create it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the tags I tried to use were unknown and I need rep:150 although a little hint to let me know would tell where I am and not get stuck.