# Cannot add tags via the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, tags, android-app, search, asking-questions

When I try to add a question on the "Android Enthusiasts" site via the Stack Exchange Android app, it doesn't allow me to add any tags. There is a text field within which to add tags on the "Ask question" page. But when I type tags, the tag search always turns up "no results." I even tried to enter tags manually, but it gets cleared all the time.

- Android version : 5.0.2

Comment: Thanks for the report! Please keep in mind that the iOS and Android apps are no longer under active development, so it may be a long time until your issue gets fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tags do not work on the Official Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235218/tags-do-not-work-on-the-official-android-app) - or did it work in the meantime? I haven't used the app frequently enough.

Comment: @Glorfindel It's worked in the meantime.

Comment: *tries to retract close vote via the iOS app but fails...*

Comment: I just tried it, and it returned the tags correctly. What keywords did you type?

Comment: I was trying to add usb-connection-mode, lenovo, 5.0-lollipop tags, but didn't work that time. I was able to add those tags on website. I just tried now, and it's working.